# error: attribute 'com.example.b3rk4.myapplication:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf' not found

Tags: java, android, gradle

When I open Android Studio my first time, I saw "**AAPT2 error: check logs for details**" this error.
When I check details wrote:

> error: attribute
>   com.example.b3rk4.myapplication:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf'
>   not found.
>
> error: attribute
>   'com.example.b3rk4.myapplication:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf' not
>   found.
>
> error: attribute
>   'com.example.b3rk4.myapplication:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf' not
>   found.
>
> error: attribute
>   'com.example.b3rk4.myapplication:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf' not
>   found.
>
> Java compiler: (1 error) error: failed linking file resources.

***What i tried already:***

1. **Open with administrator**
2. **Build->Clean Project and Build->Rebuild Project**
3. **Invalidate Caches / Restart**
4. **Add android.enableAapt2=false in gradle.properties** (When i do this "**AAPT2 error: check logs for details**" error transforming to "**Process 'command 'C:\Users\b3rk4\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\27.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1**" and when i look details:

> No resource identifier found for attribute
>   'layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf' in package
>   'com.example.b3rk4.myapplication'
>
> No resource identifier found for attribute
>   'layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf' in package
>   'com.example.b3rk4.myapplication'
>
> No resource identifier found for attribute
>   'layout_constraintRight_toRightOf' in package
>   'com.example.b3rk4.myapplication'
>
> No resource identifier found for attribute
>   'layout_constraintTop_toTopOf' in package
>   'com.example.b3rk4.myapplication'
>
> Java compiler: (3 errors)
>
> Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing
>   process
>   C:\Users\b3rk4\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\27.0.2\aapt.exe
>   with arguments {package -f --no-crunch -I
>   C:\Users\b3rk4\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-27\android.jar
>   -M \?\C:\Users\b3rk4\Desktop\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml
>   -S C:\Users\b3rk4\Desktop\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug
>   -m -J \?\C:\Users\b3rk4\Desktop\MyApplication\app\build\generated\source\r\debug
>   -F C:\Users\b3rk4\Desktop\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\resources-debug.ap_
>   --custom-package com.example.b3rk4.myapplication -0 apk --preferred-density 420dpi --output-text-symbols \?\C:\Users\b3rk4\Desktop\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug
>   --no-version-vectors}
>
> Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error
>   while executing process
>   C:\Users\b3rk4\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\27.0.2\aapt.exe
>   with arguments {package -f --no-crunch -I
>   C:\Users\b3rk4\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-27\android.jar
>   -M \?\C:\Users\b3rk4\Desktop\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml
>   -S C:\Users\b3rk4\Desktop\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug
>   -m -J \?\C:\Users\b3rk4\Desktop\MyApplication\app\build\generated\source\r\debug
>   -F C:\Users\b3rk4\Desktop\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\resources-debug.ap_
>   --custom-package com.example.b3rk4.myapplication -0 apk --preferred-density 420dpi --output-text-symbols \?\C:\Users\b3rk4\Desktop\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug
>   --no-version-vectors}
>
> Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   'C:\Users\b3rk4\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\27.0.2\aapt.exe''
>   finished with non-zero exit value 1

5. **Changed to classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'**
6. **Changed to buildToolsVersion "27.0.2"**
7. I installed Java jdk, Android Studio, Sdk thinks very carefully.
8. **Added path** C:\Users\b3rk4\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools and C:\Users\b3rk4\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
9. I unistaled everythink and installed again be carefully and noting changed...

Can you help me please? I were using Android Studio normally 1 month ago and I format my computer and then I can't use any more

**My build.gradle (project):**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**My build.gradle (Module: app):**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.b3rk4.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: DO you have `ContraintsLayout` depedency in `build.gradle`?

Comment: I added in topic, can you look and say to me?

Comment: This happens when you don't have a dependency on Constraint Layout library, but if what you've posted is correct, it looks like you already have it. It's possible that something is cached wrong and since invalidating cache through Studio didn't work, try fining the gradle cache directory on your computer and just delete the whole thing.

Comment: On windows it should be somewhere like C:\Users\<user>\.gradle

Comment: I solved. I changed .android, .AndroidStudio3.1, .gradle files with working files.